# SQLite android error

Tags: android, sqlite

can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

i am getting an error saying that the table does not have any column named description:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = (
         "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
         COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ 
         COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null," + 
         COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null," +
         COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null," +
         COLUMN_IMAGE + " text not null);");
```

Comment: did you just add this column in after the table was created?

Comment: yes i think so...what can i do please?

Comment: well that is why, just uninstall the app from the phone and you will be fine when you run it again because the database will be created with that new column

Comment: Also erase the app data, just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Erase your app's data. Adding the new column will not add it to the database intermediately. Clear your app data from app settings and when you run the app again, your database will be recreated with the new column included.